# Prove that for all $B \subseteq A$, if $Y \subseteq B$ and $F[B] \subseteq B$, then $C \subseteq B$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For a set $S=\{B:Y⊆B⊆A$ and $F[B]⊆B\}$, let $C=\bigcap S$.

Prove that for all $B \subseteq A$, if $Y \subseteq B$ and $F[B] \subseteq B$, then $C \subseteq B$.

I've already proved that $Y \subseteq C$, and $F[C] \subseteq C$.  I don't understand this question much because it seems to me that we've already defined $B \in S$ such that $Y \subseteq B$ and $F[B] \subseteq B$.  If $C$ is the set of things common to all $B$, isn't it necessary that $C \subseteq B$ for all $B \subseteq A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it's confusing because the question reuses the variable $B$ in two different contexts. Using a different name might help.

---

Let $F\colon A \to A$ and fix some $Y \subseteq A$. Let $S=\{B:Y⊆B⊆A$ and $F[B]⊆B\}$ and let $C=\bigcap S$. Now choose any $X \subseteq A$ such that $Y \subseteq X$ and $F[X] \subseteq X$. We want to show that $C \subseteq X$.

To this end, choose any $D \in C$. We want to show that $D \in X$. Indeed, notice that since $Y \subseteq X \subseteq A$ and $F[X] \subseteq X$, we know that $X \in S$. It follows that:
$$
D \in C = \bigcap S \subseteq X
$$
as desired.